# Symfony2 is not displaying the error when using createNotFoundException()

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony2 and it is not displaying an error when createNotFoundException() is called. 
It is just showing a blank white page.

Here is my code that is throwing an exception:

```
if(!$product){
     throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
}
```

The header of my class uses the following:

```
 <?php    

 namespace WIC\ProductBundle\Controller;
 use WIC\SecurityBundle\Controller\AuthorizationController;
 use WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;

 use Doctrine\Tests\Common\Annotations\Null;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

 use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

 class ProductController extends AuthorizationController
 {
     /**
      * @Route("/foo/", name="foo_bar")
      * @Template()
      */
     public function fooAction(Request $request)
     {
         $record = $em->getRepository('WICProductBundle:Product')->find(100000);
         if(!$record){
             throw new NotFoundHttpException("Test, This Is Not Valid");
         }
     }
 }
```

Now I am getting this error as well:

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "createNotFoundException" from namespace "WIC\ProductBundle\Controller" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ffss/src/WIC/ProductBundle/Controller/ProductController.php line 43. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
>
> [03-Oct-2014 04:11:32 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WIC\ProductBundle\Controller\createNotFoundException' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ffss/src/WIC/ProductBundle/Controller/ProductController.php on line 43
>   [03-Oct-2014 04:12:50 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WIC\ProductBundle\Controller\createNotFoundException' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ffss/src/WIC/ProductBundle/Controller/ProductController.php on line 43

I switched out that namespace to this and everything works fine as far as that php log error goes, still not able to pull the symfony error page.

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

All other errors are showing btw, just any exception error is not showing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [I was trying to help you before](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/41027786?noredirect=1) but you wouldn't follow my suggestions. [Deleting your old question and then reposting the exact same thing to get back on the top is frowned upon as well.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it) Would you like to try my suggestions this time? Next time you need more attention, you should try things like adding more context to your code (perhaps the full controller function.)

Comment: Also try swapping the `throw` statement with a `die()` function with the same message, see if you get that as output. Like before, I suspect you have a low-level PHP problem lying around somewhere else causing a WSOD.

Comment: Thanks, suggestion duly noted. I wasn't trying to skirt your question, just felt like my last question wasn't correctly posted, no reason to leave up a bad question. I understand now.

Comment: Yes, the die works, but doesn't give me the typical error page with all the details.

Comment: No problem - the Edit button works perfectly well, lets you fix a question if you deem it to not be of good quality, will bump your post back up to the top, etc... and maintains the comment history so other people can be up to date. Can you give more context for the `createNotFoundException`? Where is it occuring? What is the full code?

Answer (score 0):

For your new error, instead of

```
throw new createNotFoundException("Test, This Is Not Valid");
```

you should use

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException("Test, This Is Not Valid");
```

I'm still not getting enough context for your original problem though.

Comment: @LargeTuna Can you also post your full code - you're giving way too little detail for me to help that much

Comment: Thats all the code, I am just trying to generate any error by using the throw NotFoundHttpException() and it is not working. die() works NotFoundHttpException() does not. All other types of errors in symfony are working fine, just the NotFoundHttpException() is not working for me. I will post the find() as well but the result is the same.

Comment: @LargeTuna If that's the full code, you're missing a `class` declaration... and a `return` statement if `$record` is not `false`.

Comment: my bad, didnt know you needed all the class info, just posted it

Comment: @LargeTuna Okay now you need to clean up the question.. the error messages should be most recent, the code that you posted should be testable and reproducible.. you have made sure that you're using `throw new NotFoundHttpException` right?

Answer (score 0):

When php fatal error occurs it does not create any event for symfony to handle. In order to make php fatal error on your page you need to enable debugging which enables symfony ro register a shutdown function. Which version of symfony you are using? if you are using symfony version above 2.2 to enable debug simply putting $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true); is not enough. Put the below line above it to properly display any php errors (most possible reason of blank page) too. \Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug::enable(1);
 Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem when trying out the tutorial from the Symfony website (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages).

But then i noticed i forgot to extend my class with Controller

```
class HelloController extends Controller
```

after which i was able to display the custom 404 error.